# Backing up in review queues

Tags: discussion

When reviewing questions in the queue, most specifically close votes, what happens if a mistake is made?

I was reviewing a particular question that I fully intended to vote to close (it was clearly a third-party plugin question), but I inadvertently hit the "Leave Open" button.

It doesn't appear that I can go back and change my vote - either that, or I just can't find a way to do so.

Is there a way to change my vote, or is it "hard-and-fast" once set?

Comment: If you really made a mistake vote you could use the flag for moderator attention flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no vote type as "Leave Open". That button simply is a mean to skips to the next post.

If you are still on the page, you can hit the back button to review the question. Then, click the question's title to open it in a new tab. You can then use the normal "close" vote button under the post to submit your vote.

If not, you can still search the question by its title. You can also access the history of your close votes [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/close/history).

Comment: Thanks! I understand it's not a "vote type", but clicking it shows you selected to leave it open in both history and the infobox at the top of the OP. I did locate the question and selected the normal "close", and while that seems to be accepted, my original selection is what's shown in the infobox. It seems once selected, you can't change it. It's not a big deal - I just don't want to look like a dolt to others who may look at it later and recognize that it clearly should have been closed and wonder why I selected to leave it open.

Comment: I marked this as accepted and upvoted it because it is definitely correct as far as detail. But it does seem that you can't change what shows as your selection in the review infobox.